# List of default WordPress URLs

Tags: urls

I'm looking for a list of all possible URLs (or URL patterns) that would deliver content or would otherwise cause WordPress to respond to the request with something other than a 404. Let's assume a fresh standard install of the current version.

I've looked around and there's lots of documentation on how to create custom URLs to your content or admin area or for various other things, but I haven't found a comprehensive list of what exists by default. Does such a list exist or is there an easy way to compile it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently I can't offer a full answer to your question, but here as a starting point a (PHP 5.3+/closure) plugin that dumps the global `WP_Rewrite` object into the `shutdown` hook.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Show WP_Rewrite Dump at the last hook (shutdown) */

add_action( 'shutdown', function() {
    var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'] );
} );
```

This doesn't take redirects into account. If someone would for e.g. write

```
exit( wp_redirect( home_url() ) );
```

somewhere, you wouldn't know that inside `WP_Rewrite`.